# "Centralized configuration for microservices" and SI4T

Tags: web8, configuration, web8.5, si4t, microservices

I am working on an 8.1 Java project, and the microservices are using the config variable replacement (read from env.sh)

```
SDL_BASE_DIR="/home/sdl-preview"
SDL_DATA_DIR="/home/sdl-preview/sdl_web"
SDL_FS_STORAGE_DIR="/home/sdl-preview/sdl_web/temp"
SDL_FS_DATA_STORAGE_DIR="/home/sdl-preview/sdl_web/temp/data"
SDL_DEPLOYER_INCOMING="/home/sdl-preview/sdl_web/incoming
```

etc....

**First of all, can I add custom variables? I can't find much documentation on this.**

The second issue lies with SI4T. The configuration object that is passed into the Indexer isn't transformed and contains all the `${SDL_BROKER_DB_SERVER}` type string replacement values.

**Has anyone got SI4T working with the "Centralized configuration for microservices" (config variable replacemet)**

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to specify these:

1. As a system environment variable
2. Defining them in the Java Virtual Machine options
3. Defining them on the command prompt.

For example, if you have the following in your **cd_storage_conf.xml** file:

`${solrpath:-http://localhost:8080/solr/live_solr_core/}`

Then you could pass this in as a parameter to the startup script:

`./start.sh -solrpath=http://localhost:8080/solr/staging_solr_core/`

or

`./start.ps1 -solrpath=http://localhost:8080/solr/staging_solr_core/`

If you don't specify it then the default is used (`http://localhost:8080/solr/live_solr_core/`).

Or you could also specify `solrpath` as an Environment Variable.

For reference, there are some pages in the online docs on this that may help further:

[Storage Layer configuration parameters](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-39E1F200-1163-4A16-BCFF-F2E539B3498F)

[About parameters in the Ambient Data Framework configuration](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-CC9C478C-5594-4BBE-B7F9-A98DA5ADAB5D)

---

Update: My suspicions about being able to add your own custom variables is also backed up by the following statement on the [SDL Web 8.1.1 – Optimizations](https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/b/feed/posts/sdl-web-8-1-1-optimizations) article on the SDL Community site:

> You can now use parameters in the storage configuration file, for items such as database names, servers or passwords **(and anything else you want)**. These properties can be then set either in environment variables or as parameters when the service is initiated.

Comment: I think that the custom variables are fine, but SI4T seems to be reading the raw file, not the "compiled" file.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Hopefully my answer helps with the "First of all, can I add custom variables? I can't find much documentation on this." question for anyone who comes across this. I understand your problem with SI4T reading the non-compiled version now. Maybe someone from the SDL Cloud team or the SI4T team can help with this part.

Answer (score 1):

Quick warning, as you are mentioning `env.sh`. If `env.sh` is used as a variable file (using the `EnvironmentFile` directive) in a systemd service configuration file you cannot use expressions in `env.sh`, only simple assignments.

So `VARNAME="value"` works, but `VARNAME="${OTHERVAR}/value"` does not work. You can only have simple assignments, which are then added to the environment by systemd.

Comment: Thanks, I have only used simple assignments, do you know if it works with SI4T? That is the main issue I am having.

Answer (score 0):

SI4T unfortunately makes use of the legacy Configuration mechanism in order to stay backwards compatible with Tridion 2013 / 2011, which means environment properties are indeed not parsed. An enhancement issue is raised here: https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/issues/15.